# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (x-5)^n}{(2^n-3) \ln(n+3)}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Find the radius and interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (x-5)^n}{(2^n-3) \ln(n+3)}$. What should I do here? I know that first I need to apply the ratio test, taking the absolute value of this function, $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$, and after that, take the analysis of the evaluated limit and go for $(\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|) < 1$. After finding the value of x that is < 1, I should evaluate the edge cases. But how do I find this interval of convergence? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Leibniz criterion.

Comment: Once you take the limit in the Ratio Test, you will have a result $$ \ | \ (x-5) · k \ | \ < \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ |  x-5  | \ < \ \frac{1}{k} \ \ , $$ $ k \ $ being a number you need to work out. So $ \ \frac{1}{k} \ $ is the radius of convergence and this resulting expression describes the interval of convergence.  (You of course still need to check the endpoints of the interval.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make the radius of convergence to be $2$, not $1$, so our interval is at least $(3, 7)$, plus or minus some endpoints. We have to consider these endpoints separately, and there's no silver bullet or mechanical method for figuring out the convergence of these endpoints. All we know for sure is that the ratio test will be useless from here on out!

That said, alternating series test, as suggested by vitamin d, is often a good tool for one of the endpoints (the one that alternates signs), and it helps us here now. If we take $x = 7$, then our series becomes
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{2^n}{(2^n - 3) \ln(n + 3)}.$$
The alternating series test applies to series of the form $\sum (-1)^n a_n$, where $a_n \to 0$ monotonically (or eventually monotonically is fine; it doesn't matter if the terms have some initial bumps, so long as they start decreasing to $0$ after a while). In our case, we take
$$a_n = \frac{2^n}{(2^n - 3) \ln(n + 3)} = \frac{2^n}{2^n - 3} \cdot \frac{1}{\ln(n + 3)} = \left(1 + \frac{3}{2^n - 3}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\ln(n + 3)}.$$
For $n \ge 2$, we have $2^n - 3 \ge 1$. As $n \to \infty$, the sequence $2^n - 3$ is increasing and positive for $n \ge 2$, so $1 + \frac{3}{2^n - 3}$ is decreasing to $1$. On the other hand, $\frac{1}{\ln(n + 3)}$ decreases to $0$ for $n \ge 0$. Thus, their product decreases to $0$ from $n = 2$ onwards. The test then tells us that the series converges.

Now, consider the $n = 3$ case. In this case we get,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(-2)^n}{(2^n - 3) \ln(n + 3)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(2^n - 3) \ln(n + 3)}.$$
Now, recall that $\frac{2^n}{2^n - 3} \to 1$, so this series is "close" to the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n + 3)}.$$
The logarithm grows to $\infty$ much slower than just $n$, so we should be able to prove that the series diverges, using the harmonic series.

Let's make this formal, using a variant of the limit comparison test. Consider:
$$\frac{1}{n} \div \left(\frac{2^n}{(2^n - 3) \ln(n + 3)}\right) = \frac{2^n - 3}{2^n} \times \frac{\ln(n + 3)}{n}.$$
The former factor converges to $1$. The latter factor we can evaluate using L'Hopital's rule (we need to assume for the moment that $n$ is a continuous variable). We get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n + 3)}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n + 3}}{1} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n + 3} = 0.$$
Thus our quotient tends to $1 \times 0 = 0$. In particular, the quotient must eventually be less than $1$, so for sufficiently large $n$,
$$\frac{1}{n} \div \left(\frac{2^n}{(2^n - 3) \ln(n + 3)}\right) < 1 \implies \frac{2^n}{(2^n - 3) \ln(n + 3)} > \frac{1}{n}.$$
Therefore, by the comparison test, and the fact that the harmonic series diverges, our series diverges too, so $7$ does not belong to our interval. Our interval is therefore $(3, 7]$.